# Probability distribution of functions of random variables

Tags: self-study, survival, exponential-distribution

A system will function as long as at least one of three components functions.

When all three components are functioning, the distribution of the life of each is exponential with parameter $\frac{1}{3}\lambda$. When only two are functioning, the distribution of the life of each of the two is exponential with parameter $\frac{1}{2}\lambda$; and when only one is functioning, the distribution of its life is exponential with parameter $\lambda$.

1. What is the distribution of the system?
2. Suppose now that only one component (of the three components) is used at a time and it is replaced when it fails. What is the distribution of the lifetime of such a system?

   I have tried the problem in this way..It may be wrong.

Let us consider three events $A$:When all the three components are functioning.

$B$:When two components are functioning

$C$:When only one is functioning

We have to compute the joint distribution of these three events.How can this be done?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake.I am a new user of this site.So I know a little about the rules.The problem given is not my homework.I was just doing the exercises and I don't know how to deal with these types of problems.I am just a new learner of this subject.Hope I will get a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for adding the tag, @PriyankaBanik. We welcome questions like this, but we treat them differently. Please read the tag's wiki, linked above. A lot of people show up here hoping to get their HW done for them, so we have little tolerance for that. This may not actually be your HW, but it falls into the same category. If you can state what you understand & have tried thus far, we can try to help you.

Comment: Are you sure it says in the assignment that the remaining lifetime of the components depends on what happens with the other components? Rather, I suspect you mean that the instantaneous rate of failing for a component is $\frac{1}{3}\lambda$, $\frac{1}{2}\lambda$ or $\lambda$ depending on how many of the other two components have already failed. This still not really makes sense because component life times are usually independent from each other, but it *is* conceivable and answers to your questions could be calculated.

Comment: @whuber. My apologies, I will try to adhere to the forum rules in the future.

Comment: As a teacher, I thank you for this nice exercise, my students will suffer on it :)

Comment: @Stijn No apologies are needed! Every forum has its own peculiarities that take a little time to get used to. We are grateful for your interest and your helpful posts.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your cooperation.I am also confused with the language given in the question.I think the component life times are independent of each other.Then how can we find the distribution?